# Android sticky headers with multiple sections per header

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I need to create a `ListView` or `RecyclerView` that is based on calendar with multiple sections.

Let's say I have 300 items that needs to be visible to the user.

I need to show the list in sections of week. So list needs to have a "header" section that says "May 21 - May 27". Let's say 4 items fall within those dates (see image below)

So I want to show each individual date as a sub-header and show items for those dates.

I've looked at MANY MANY examples about header list views and adapters and so on ([DoubleStickyHeadersList](https://github.com/Kenber/DoubleStickyHeadersList), [StickyHeaders](https://github.com/ShamylZakariya/StickyHeaders), [HeaderListView](http://applidium.github.io/HeaderListView/) and so many more).

There is no error or logcat for me to show. **I just can't find a way to show header (date range title) and sub-header (individual date) working at the same time.**

Also, **how would I go about jumping to a specific date?** If I want to scroll automatically to May 28th when screen loads.

Example of what list should look like:
[image]